# What is the difference between initialize and initiate?

Tags: american-english, subcontinental-english

What is the difference between **initialize** and **initiate** words? Where should we use and can somebody explain it with some examples.

Comment: Interesting question -- +1 to counteract the baloney downvote.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

They both imply we start something

**Initiate:**

> Cause (a process or action) to begin: "initiate discussions".

**Initialize/Initialise:**

> Set to the value or put in the condition appropriate to the start of an operation.

Also if you initiate something, it is your initiative, whereas if you initialise something, you can have been asked to do so.

In programming, we use the word initialise, when we declare a variable and give it an initial value

Comment: As the word is virtually nonexistent in Google NGrams before 1950, I suspect it's only used in computing.

Comment: [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/interactive_chart?content=initiate%2C+initialize&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1600&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cinitiate%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Binitiate%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BInitiate%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cinitialize%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Binitialize%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BInitialize%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BINITIALIZE%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: I feel an ngram is meaningless here. The two words are used in different contexts

Answer (score 6):

*Initiate* means to start something, and there is often (though not always) an implication that this is something new, that has never been done before.

*Initialize* means to set a system to a starting state. This may be one step (or even the only step) in *initiating* the system.

Answer (score 1):

**Initiate** means to start, engage, or begin something.

**Initialize** means to take the beginning letters of something. For example, United States of America becomes USA. Such initialization is very common. It can also mean to apply initial value to something that will have a variable value, over time.

Comment: Do you have any documentation for the "Take beginning letters" meaning?
https://wikidiff.com/acronym/initialization

Comment: You are "forming an acronym" or "abbreviating" United States of America. You are not "Initializing" by taking the initials of something or someone.